# Laravel many-to-many relationship on the same model

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, relationship

I have a model `Job`.

A `Job` can require other `Jobs` be completed before it can begin.

A `Job` may be the pre-required job for many `Jobs` at once.

So, say `Job A` depends on `Job B` and `Job C`, I would like to be able to call `job->requiredJobs` and get those two jobs.

As it stands, I have the following:

```
class Job extends Model
{

    public function requiredJobs() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Job', 'required_job_id');
    }
}
```

However, I'm finding that if I create a `Job D` and have it require `Job B` and `Job C`, it overrides `Job A`'s required jobs field, since it seems to be adding `required_job_id` onto the required jobs, instead of creating an array on the dependent job.

Hope this all makes sense! I'm not entirely sure if I need two definitions, or if `hasMany` is the wrong relationship (`belongsToMany` instead?...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36205924/1191044)'s answer pushed me in the right direction.

Here is how I ended up defining my model:

```
class Job extends Model
{

    public function requiredJobs() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Job', null, 'dependent_job_ids', 'required_job_ids');
    }

    public function dependentJobs() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Job', null, 'required_job_ids', 'dependent_job_ids');
    }
}
```

This meant that when I call `dependentJob->requiredJobs()->save(requiredJob)`, a couple things happen:

1. `dependentJob` gets an array of IDs `required_job_ids`, and I can call `dependentJob->requiredJobs` to get the entire list of job models.
2. `requiredJob` gets an array of IDs `dependent_job_ids`, and I can call `requiredJob->dependentJobs` to get the entire list of job models.

Works like a charm!

Comment: Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

For a [Many To Many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), `belongsToMany()` is the correct method but you'll also need a pivot table to store the links.

Answer (score 1):

This is just to add on anyone looking for a solution on the same issue, relating the same model.

Here you can create a joining table with normal `Many to Many` Relationships and attach ids as normal Laravel relationships

```php
public function requiredJobs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Job','dependent_jobs_required_jobs','dependent_job_ids','required_job_ids');
}

public function dependentJobs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Job','dependent_jobs_required_jobs','required_job_ids','dependent_job_ids');
}
```